# How to concatenate float to list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
z = pd.DataFrame({'Unit':['%','%','%','mmol/mol','mmol/mol'],'value':[6,1,5,120,110]})
```

I would like to create a new column called `new_value` which will have a value based on `Unit` column. Meaning, if the `unit` is `%`, we just retain the same. If otherwise, we should apply the below formula to convert them

```
% = [0.09148 * value] + 2.152).
```

Therefore, I tried the below code

```
z['new_value'] = np.where(z["Unit"]=='mmol/mol', z['value'],([0.09148*z['value']] + 2.152))
```

But it resulted in an error message as shown below

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[]` for return 1d array from second part (else) from `np.where`, also change order `then-else`:

```
z['new_value'] = np.where(z["Unit"]=='mmol/mol', 0.09148*z['value'] + 2.152, z['value'])
print (z)
       Unit  value  new_value
0         %      6     6.0000
1         %      1     1.0000
2         %      5     5.0000
3  mmol/mol    120    13.1296
4  mmol/mol    110    12.2148
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
z["new_value"] = z["value"]
mask = z['Unit'] != '%', "new_value"
z.loc[mask] = z.loc[mask] * 0.09148 + 2.152
```

```
       Unit  value  new_value
0         %      6     6.0000
1         %      1     1.0000
2         %      5     5.0000
3  mmol/mol    120    13.1296
4  mmol/mol    110    12.2148
```